# Asp.Net GridView - Need to add next and previous button in popup

Tags: asp.net

I have account audit search page that display list of records in grid view. for example - name,Id,action etc.

When I click on any row in grid view the details of that row I am displaying in another aspx page as popup.I have my grid view in audit search page and showing details in detailsModal page.

When I am clicking on row in grid view I am passing rowId to detailsmodal page and in details modal page based on rowId I am fetching the data and showing it.

for example - window.showModalDialog("DetailsModal.aspx?RowId=" + rowId, '', modalSize);

Now I want to add next and previous button on detailsModal page so when I click on next button the next row of gridview should be displayed in detailsModal page and when I click on previous button the previous row of gridview should be displayed.

What I have tried:

Please suggest. It will be nice if I can get some sample code as example in solution.

Comment: Your "what I have tried" section is blank. Have you tried nothing or is that a mistake?

Comment: I am new to this so not tried anything and need suggestions .Thanks